# HTML jquery buttons sometimes don't react

Tags: jquery, html, function, button

Hi I have a few simple buttons which sometimes don't react. It happens rarely but I still don't like it. It happens more if you click very fast or change the navigation very very fast. This is the code I have for them :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('[id*=txt]').hide();
    $('[id*=hd]').hide();                   
    $('[id*=home]').show();
    $('#btnhome').css('background-color',"#555");
    $('#btnhome').css('opacity',"0.4");

    $('.button').click(function (){
        $('[id*=txt]').hide();
        $('[id*=hd]').hide();
        $('.button').css('background',"transparent");
        $('.button').css('opacity',"1");
        $(this).css('background-color',"#555");
        $(this).css('opacity',"0.4");
   });          

    $('#btnhome').click(function () {   
        $('[id*=home]').show();             
    });     

    $('#btnabout').click(function () {              
        $('[id*=about]').show();        
    });    

    $('#btncontact').click(function () {        
        $('[id*=contact]').show();  
    });
});
```

They are only used for showing and hiding the text and they also change the color opacity and so on when they are clicked. When they don't react nothing happens at all, as if I don't have any click function defined.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/3/)

^This is what I'm basically using, try hitting them in a random order and switching in a fast way (happens more if you do it fast). You'll see that sometimes they don't react. Its a little bit harder to notice because it happens rarely (sometimes more often) so it wont probably happen at first but it sure happens. So give it a try a good few times and you'll see what I'm talking about. The more fast and random you do it the more it will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with your demo, I noticed that the issue was occurring when clicking a certain place on each button, not by clicking them randomly or at a certain speed. The sweet spot is usually on the right side at the edge of the button text at the padding.

I found that removing the `.button:active{}` pseudo-class from your CSS fixes the issue, so my guess is that the shifting of the positioning of the button in the css is interfering with the click event. My suggestion would be to incorporate the removed CSS styling into the click (or mousedown) event itself rather than the `:active` pseudoclass.

Comment: You're right! I just wanted to say : I have noticed when the button doesn't react, if you click on the exact pixel again it wont work until you hit another position on it. So if you're hitting the same pixel over and over again it wont work till you move your mouse and click on it but some other pixel/position. Is there any way I could only move the text on the button but not the whole button?

Comment: Take a look at this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/8/
I moved all of the styling that you had in the `active` psuedoclass to the jquery `mousedown` event. You also have to implement a `mouseup` event in order to remove those styles after the click.

Comment: Damn, it still does happen. 'mousedown' didn't fix it.

Comment: Problem is in the `.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top: 2px;
    left:2px;
}` Not the pseudo class but more what is inside it. Problem itself is the top and left positioning styling...

Comment: I tried some other methods of changing the position of the button when it is clicked, and they all seem to have the same issue. Something to do with moving the button out from underneath itself, but I really don't know exactly what's going on. My suggestion would be to try and achieve the same effect by changing the border style or by using a background image and changing that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but I suppose that the problem is because when you use the selector like this:

```
 $('[id*=contact]').myFunction();
```

JQuery it spend more time to find the right selector and don't react if they didn't found it before the next click.
It's possible that in a complex page, full of divs and information, the malfunction can be emphatized.

A support of this, I tried to change only the onclick callbacks, and it seems to be works better: http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/7/

Comment: Unfortunately to me it still seems the same as before. When the button doesn't react, if you click on the exact pixel again it wont work until you hit another position on it. So if you're hitting the same pixel over and over again it wont work till you move your mouse and click on it but some other pixel/position.